# What does "low" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> That's some 3rd world begging skill right there. Obviously she isn't from here, but that's low as f***.

The comment was made based on [this video](http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshh48yfMrcZM3zMUtpX).

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74766/does-hit-a-new-low-have-the-meaning-other-than-number-and-record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=low) first definition: (which I agree with)

> An action that is considered bad morally, unfair or dirty. Shows
>   disapproval of the action by the speaker. Dude you dumped Bob on his
>   birthday for his best friend? That's pretty low...
>
> You kicked him in his broken leg? That's low....

Answer (score 2):

***Low*** in this context means ***unfair or dishonest***.[¹](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/low#low_42)

*American Heritage Dictionary Of Idioms* says ***low blow*** was first attested around 1950, and means an unfair attack, alluding “to the illegal practice of hitting an opponent in boxing below the belt”.